# Query on DML Rows calculation in logs for M-D Relationships

Tags: apex

I had 213 records in a Custom object (Expense__c).

This custom object has a child (ExpenseChild__c).

Every 213 parent records had a corresponding child record in the child object.

When I did a delete via this code snippet, it deleted all the parent records but in the log it shows only 213 as DML Rows in that transaction.

```
delete new List<Expense__c>([SELECT ID FROM Expense__c]);
```

Ideally it should have been 213 x (1+1) = 426..right ? because child records also got deleted implicitly because of M-D relationship.

Can someone explain the rationale behind why the child records which got deleted via this DML did not get into account in the log for the "DML rows"[image] ?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the child records were deleted? With a M-D, its possible to reparent child records and not have them deleted when parent records are deleted. It all depends on how you set up the objects when you created the M-D relationship. Delete child records is now optional.

Comment: Yes. I can confirm that the child records indeed got deleted.

Comment: I think this is by design - the logged Number of DML rows are the # of rows in the list of sobjects passed to the delete call.